# Which Function is triggered when play button is clicked in JW Player?

Tags: jwplayer

I am using JW Player in my application. I want to know which function is triggered when the play button is clicked in the JW Player.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you trying to do? What version of JWPlayer?

You can simulate a "Play" click in JWPlayer 4 by doing this:
http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player4Api#Sendingevents

```
player.sendEvent("PLAY","true");
```

Otherwise if you want to do something when the video is played you need to listen for the event.

```
var player = null;
function playerReady(thePlayer) {
 player = document.getElementById(thePlayer.id);
 addListeners();
}


function addListeners() {
 if (player) { 
  player.addModelListener("STATE", "stateListener");
 } else {
  setTimeout("addListeners()",100);
 }
}
function stateListener(obj) { //IDLE, BUFFERING, PLAYING, PAUSED, COMPLETED
 currentState = obj.newstate; 
 previousState = obj.oldstate; 

 var tmp = document.getElementById("stat");
 if (tmp) { 
  tmp.innerHTML = "current state: " + currentState + 
  "<br>previous state: " + previousState; 
 }

 if ((currentState == "COMPLETED")&&(previousState == "PLAYING")) {
  document.location.href="http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/"; 
 }
}
```